# edit row with php / mysql, something wrong my with variables

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I've been working on this code for days & i just can't figure out the problem.

I want to edit a row from a html table with php.

I keep getting the following error

*Notice: Undefined variable: naam in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_edit\edit.php on line 38
Notice: Undefined variable: dier in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_edit\edit.php on line 39*

these lines are at the $query part from my code

I got 2 files 
an index file with the following code for the edit page:

```
<td><a   href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['id']. "\" > edit </a>
```

And the edit page after the database connection:

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    $dier = $_POST['dier'];
}

$queryDetail = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ".$id;
$resultDetail = mysqli_query($conn, $queryDetail);
$album = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDetail);

$query = "UPDATE $tbl
          SET 'naam'='$naam',
          'dier' = '$dier'
          WHERE id = '$id'";

$examp = mysqli_query($conn, $query);    
?>


<html>
</html><h1>Wijzig hier de gegevens</h1>
 <fo

rm action="home.php?id=<?= $id ?>"  method="post" >


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-25">
                <label for="naam"> Vul hier de nieuwe gebruikers naam in: </label>
            </div></div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-75">
                <input type="text" name="naam" required="required" value="<?= $album['naam'] ?>"/>
```

etc etc

Can someone explain to me why i keep getting errors ):

Comment: 1st: because you reach the page via a normal link the passes params are found in `$_GET`, not in post. 2nd $_POST['submit'] wont be set, for first reason and because it's not passed in the link. Therefore you never reach `$naam = $_POST['naam'];` -> $naam isn't set.

Comment: 3rd: you should wrap everything till `<html>` in `if($_POST['submit']) { }`

Comment: 4th: get your logic of states right. in the second script you have 3 possible states: coming from edit-link ($_GET !), coming from formsubmit ($_POST !), hitting directly without even sending an id. Now: When do you update? When do you select? It's all in one row now...

Comment: now you have the odd situation, that when you would submit the form and update $naam you would _still see_ the old values in the form afterwards...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Comment: Note that 'naam' is a string. \`naam\` is a column identifier. See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the errors because you are only defining the variables if the variable `$_POST['submit']` is set, and most probably it isn't being sent.

Then you are trying to use that variables, which are undefined.

Try changing the method you use to check if it have been submitted or include the code that need the submitted values (MYSQLi part) inside the variable check